# Video tag html5 is not working in IOS devices

Tags: reactjs, iphone, html5-video

I am using video tag in react, it is working will in desktop, android, but it doesn't work in iphone (both chrome and safiri).

This is code I wrote in react:

```
<video
  width="1920"
  height="1080"
  autoPlay
  loop
  muted
  playsInline
  className={headerStyle.video}
  id="intro-video"
>
  <source
    src={bgVideoUri}
    type="video/mp4"
  />
</video>
```

It is html generated:

```
<video width="1920" height="1080" autoplay loop playsinline class="header-module--video--a5s_G" id="intro-video">
  <source src="my_url_to_mp4_video" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

In Iphone the video is shown:

[image]

When clicking the `play` button, nothing happens.

Please help me if you have encountered this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any errors in console for the iphone?

Comment: @designtocode how can we can log in console of iphone ?

Comment: You can plug the iphone into a mac and inspect in Safari desktop. Here's a guide https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-debug-on-iphone

Comment: it looks like you lost the muted attribute somehow.  If you had autoplay & muted, the video will autoplay in the browser.

Comment: If it fails only on iOS, I wonder if it is a format issue.  What is the video encoded as (you can check at https://ffprobe.a.video)

Comment: You need to check the video format. It might be H263 put inside MP4 container but on iOS you need H264 or H265 only in MP4 container.